# Did Sarojini Naidu say this: When the house is on fire, the poet should stop singing...?

Tags: quote-source, sarojini-naidu

Did Sarojini Naidu say something about this:

> "When the house is on fire, the poet should stop singing, and get the
>   buckets to put out the fire."

I got this from a FB [post](https://www.facebook.com/169234266466751/photos/a.169253569798154.39496.169234266466751/1195288420527992/?type=3&comment_id=1195326127190888&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R%22%7D). But I want to find out the original source of this quote.

Any ideas?

Comment: Here's a lead: https://twitter.com/QuoteResearch/status/856024879002472449